# Efficient method to find a unique value within a worksheet - preferably not VLOOKUP

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a sheet of 13000 rows of data, 10 columns wide. I need to find a unique value within column 2 and report on corresponding values from the row with the unique value.

I've tried VLOOKUP but since the data has gaps or data in some cells can be either numeric or text this method seems complex. I've tried a more basic find e.g `Worksheets("IMPORT").Columns(2).Find("17013").Row` but this seemed slow therefore I've used:

```
Set foundCell = Sheets("IMPORT").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(What:="17013", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Found_row = foundCell.Row

MsgBox Found_row
```

This seems a bit quicker. In this case I'm looking for 17013, and once I've found the row I can report on other data in the row to a userform. I find that after about 60 enquiries Excel seems to shut down so I was wondering is there is a more efficient method to search for a unique value?

Comment: I'm curious what did you mean by "unique" value ? From your code, it seems you want to find a certain value (the value is unique or not, only the user know). In the first code, you want to find a value within column 2.... in the second code, you want to find a value anywehre within A1.currentregion. Or did you mean (for example) in the rows of column 2, you have data something like this : `1,2,3,1,1,4,4,3,5,6,6,7,7` ---> from those data, you want a macro to give you a result : 2 and 5 because the other data are not unique but duplicate. Please CMIIW.

Comment: The unique value is from a series of bar codes from a list of 13000 products. No two bar codes are the same hence each search is for a unique number that resides in Column 2. The code is part of a stock management project, scan the bar code and present the user with associated stock info. The code as presented is part of a series of user forms.

Answer (score 1):

### Find in Column

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("IMPORT")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(2)
    
    Dim rIndex: rIndex = Application.Match("17013", crg, 0)
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    
    If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
        Set fCell = crg.Cells(rIndex)
        MsgBox "Found in cell " & fCell & ".", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the row number of the single and unique value inside a range use:

```
Public Function GET_ROW(ByVal searchRng As Range) As Long
'searchRng must be a single column range and must contain a SINGLE unique value
GET_ROW = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(" & searchRng.Address & "," & searchRng.Address & ")=1)*ROW(" & searchRng.Address & "))")
End Function
```

This UDF will work **only** if there's a **single** unique value in the range. If you got more than 1 it won't work as expected.

**If you already know what the unique value is** and you just need the row number use:

```
Public Function MATCH_ROW(ByVal searchRng As Range, ByVal searchValue As Long) As Long
'searchrng must be a single column range

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    MATCH_ROW = .Match(searchValue, searchRng.EntireColumn, 0)
End With
End Function
```

Notice in both cases `searchRng` is a single column range and `searchValue` is numeric. If you are searching for strings, change this part.

[image]